# implementing shell commands not working in ICS?

Tags: android, shell-exec, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to remove the mini apps tray from the touch wiz launcher in samsung galaxy tab 2 using the shell command like this.

```
           Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
        proc = runtime.exec("su");
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
        String cmd="mount -o remount rw /system/framework";
        osw.write(cmd+"\n");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cmd, 1).show();
        String miniapp = "mv /system/framework/minimode.jar /system/framework/modeminix.jar";

        osw.write(miniapp+"\n");}catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
```

when i run this directly in adb shell it works fine but when i run it through my app nothing changes... can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     osw.write("mount -o remount rw /system\n");
```

this works but wen u try to mount /system/framework directly it throws mount command not found :)